# How to work out the percentage of an inputted number?

Tags: python

I've started using python a few days ago and am having difficulty in adding 20% (VAT) of the answer to 'Enter the total cost of the meal'. So, say the user inputted 80, how would I get it to add 20% of the inputted answer (80) to the total cost? Thank you in advance!

```
quotient = 1 / 5
percentage = quotient * 100

total_cost = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: '))
total_cost_vat=total_cost+percentage
print("Total cost of meal inclusive of VAT is",total_cost_vat)
number_of_people = float(input('Enter the number of people paying: '))
var1 = float(input(total_cost_vat / number_of_people))
```

Comment: You forgot to multiply your percentage with the user's input. You want to do `total_cost_vat = total_cost + percentage*total_cost`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a math question, not a programming question. At the very least, you should try to think about what needs to be done, as you would do it if you had to do it yourself - with pencil and paper. If I directly asked you to get the cost inclusive of VAT, given a base price of 80, would you first compute the number 20 as the percentage, and then add 20 to 80 to get 100? Is that the correct answer? No? What steps *would* you follow? What *is* the correct answer? To write code, you must be able to answer such questions first.

Answer (score 0):

You first create a variable `quotient` and you make it equal `1/5` or `0.2`.
But now you times it by 100? Why? And then instead of multiplying `total_cost_vat` you add basically `20` to it. Why?

```
vat_percentage = 0.2 # In math 0.2 is 20%

subtotal_cost = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: '))

# Add 1 to the percentage to get total + vat
total_cost = subtotal_cost * (1 + vat_percentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the tax is going to be 20% every time you calculate the VAT you can just multiply the total cost by 1.2, otherwise you can have the tax as a variable in decimal form. Then you multiply the pre tax cost by 1 + the tax.

```
tax = 0.20

pre_tax = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: '))
total_cost_vat = pre_tax * (1 + tax)

print("Total cost of meal inclusive of VAT is",total_cost_vat)

number_of_people = float(input('Enter the number of people paying: '))

print(total_cost_vat / number_of_people)
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded it up below and annotated it. Some of the code you had wasn't necessary.

If you don't know that it is always going to be 20% you can use the below code and change the value of the variable:

```
# step 1: simpler than 1/5
percentage = 0.2 

# step 2: getting input
total_cost = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: ')) 

# step 3: calculating the cost with the vat
total_cost_vat = total_cost + (percentage * total_cost) 

# step 4: printing our value
print(total_cost_vat) # printing vat value
```

If you do know the value of the vat you can replace step 3 with below code:

```
total_cost_vat = 1.2 * total_cost
```

Hope this helped!